# How to make Own HTML5 Player from using google Drive Embeded code of a Video (Having Full screen Option eneable)?

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api

This is the embeded Code of the file:

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wdg0Wi7r37NS_DezA_qtlU2FgAAVD_agEw/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

If I use this embeded code The Video having an option with popout (at the Upper Right Corner) and There is no full Screen Mode . Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

In the iframe tag you can add the property allowfullscreen="true"

so that video would be like this

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wdg0Wi7r37NS_DezA_qtlU2FgAAVD_agEw/preview" width="640" height="480" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Check it and let me know if it didn't work for you.